# Kendo UI datasource fetch not fetching

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo UI datasource that calls a fetch function.  3 results are returned for the dataSource.  but the fetch does not excute and populate my array.

What am i missing.  The read call works perfectly.  The callback to function inside the fetch isnt running.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "../api/User/GetUsers",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                }
            }
        });
        var arr = [];
        var len =null;

        dataSource.fetch(function(){
            var data = dataSource.data();
            len = data.length;
            console.log(data.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                console.log(data[i]); // displays "Chai"
                arr.push(data[i]);
            }

        });
```

**UPDATE FIXED**
Thank you @NathanPrather the answer was in the "json" instead of "jsonp"

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "../api/User/GetUsers",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: So the Console.log is displaying the results for date.length?  I think the fetch() method is what actually calls the read method so I don't think the read is working...  If the URL is on your local machine, you don't need to use jsonp and can just use json...

Comment: I can step through the GetUSers code in VS so im sure the read is excuting.

Comment: @NathanPrather thank you it was the json instead of jsonp.  Also it is taking longer then i expected.  I need to cover scheduler in the and ajax panel